# Explain the inferencing rule

Tags: marklogic, semantic-web, marklogic-9

I have triples loaded into MarkLogic as managed triples. Specifically, all the triples correspond to the SKOS and SKOS-XL schemas. I am issuing a SPARQL query where I am looking for all subjects that are of type `<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept>`. This could be direct, or through a subclass relationship. So, when issuing the query, I am using the **rdfs.rules** ruleset for inferencing. This works, except I am also picking up subjects that are of type `<http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#Label>` that are inferred to also be of type `<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept>`. Is there any way I can see the chain of rules that is generating this triple?

I am executing something like:

```
import module namespace sem = "http://marklogic.com/semantics" at "/MarkLogic/semantics.xqy";


    let $iris := ("urn:x-evn-master:ISOCountries2017-11-13") ! sem:iri(.)
    let $bindings := map:map()
    let $_ := map:put($bindings, "inSet", $iris)
    let $_ := map:put($bindings, "s", sem:iri("https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:AN_EXACT_SYN__AN_"))
    let $rs := sem:ruleset-store("rdfs.rules", sem:store())

    return
        sem:sparql('
            select ?p ?o where {
                graph ?g {
                  ?s ?p ?o .
                }
                FILTER(?g IN (?inSet))
            }
        ', $bindings, (), $rs)
```

This is returning me:

```
<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept>
<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>   <http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#Label>
<http://www.w3.org/2008/05/skos-xl#literalForm> "AN"@en
```

Comment: 1. In your SPARQL query, where `skos:Concept` occurs? 2. Perhaps you could use SPARQL property paths in order to match "indirect" relations.

Comment: By walking through the various sub rule sets that make up the rdfs rule set I was able to determine that when I included range.rules that the inference showed up. Based on this, I was able to fix my issue. But it would be useful to be able to determine what triples were used to drive a given assertion (like a given URI is a skos:Concept)

Comment: I suppose this was the [rdfs3](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-mt/#patterns-of-rdfs-entailment-informative) rule. Without knowing  your data, it is hard to answer what triples were used.

Comment: The code you shared seems to be doing the opposite of what you are saying. You look at particular subjects, and then look at the result to check if there are skos:Concept types among them. Why not use something like `where { ?s a skos:Concept }`, together with inferencing. That would return you the subjects of direct or indirect type skos:Concept. You are currently selecting and returning all predicates and objects linked to the subjects you provide via $bindings..

Comment: @grtjn my query was what I used to troubleshoot the issue. I did query for skos concepts as you stated, and I got more than I bargained for. Turns out the issue was a mistaken rdf:range definition.